# Structuring Many-Factor Data for Linear Regression in R

Tags: r, regression, categorical-data, large-data

I have a fairly large dataset of the following form, and I want to run a linear regression returning coefficients for each factor:

```
Case    Variable1   Variable2   Result
1       Factor1     FactorA     50
2       Factor2     FactorA     60
3       Factor1     FactorB     55
4       Factor2     FactorB     65
...     ...         ...         ...
```

Running a linear regression using `lm()` on this would be very straightforward, but the size of the dataset seems to be too large.  I have about 1,000,000 cases, with about 10,000 factors in each variable.

`lm()` (or other standard linear regression methods) translates this to an extremely wide matrix where each factor is a Boolean variable, correct?  So ~ 20,000 wide x 1,000,000 tall?  Running `lm()` on just a 25,000 case sample still takes several minutes and over a gb of memory.

My initial thought was to attack this regression problem using package `biglm`, but for it to behave properly, I believe `biglm` requires every factor to be present in every "chunk" of data it digests.  This would not occur in my data; some of the factors are only present a few times.  This is called *rank deficiency*, I believe. (However, an answer at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10502882/r-biglm-with-categorical-variables) indicates there might be a workaround?)

So my question: is there a better way to structure my data to run this regression?  Is there a better package or approach I should be using to run this analysis?

Comment: Found another source that touches on possible ways to solve the rank deficiency issue with `biglm`: [Biglm predict Error message](http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/58290-Biglm-predict-Error-message-quot-Error-in-x-*-coef%28object%29-non-conformable-arguments-quot)